# Nativescript - how to clear a css settings in Javascript

Tags: nativescript

I'd like to clear a css setting in javascript.

e.g.

element.style.backgroundImage = ... // clear this property

Can this be done?

The problem is I use this inside a list-view element population and
since listview reuses underlying ui objects - sometimes it's set -
i'd like to reset it.

Comment: Post how you are setting the property in the first place.

Comment: I set it something like element.style.backgroundImage = "url(some-valid-image)"; but later I'd like to clear the background-image.

Comment: And I try to clear it by setting to an empty string